# offline fulltext search with synonyms

Tags: full-text-search, offline, synonym

I'd like to provide an offline version of my website with fulltext search. Most of the website is only pure HTML + JavaScript. But I need fulltext search with synonyms in a non-English language.

Firstly, I was thinking about [Wapache](http://www.virtualvinodh.com/technology/110-wapache-for-desktop-php-applications), because the website uses PHP, but it doesn't have mysql (and I can hardly force users to install and configure mysql), there is no pspell support, it uses old PHP 5.0.3 (witch is not the worst) and probably wouldn't work on an old IE version (the site will have a lot of JavaScript...).

Anther solution I found was Lucene. But It seems not to be supported. Its documentation [Can I use Lucene to index text in Chinese, Japanese, Korean, and other multi-byte character sets?](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Can_I_use_Lucene_to_index_text_in_Chinese.2C_Japanese.2C_Korean.2C_and_other_multi-byte_character_sets.3F) refers to a non-existent page "Lucene Sandbox". I also found out that it does not support synonyms.

I have also found a reference to [WorldNet](http://opensource.ebswift.com/WordNet.Net/), witch could add support for synonyms to Lucene, but only for English.

So, the question is, how I can make an offline web application with non-English synonyms aware fulltext and, if possible, without the need to install anything to the user's computer (of course java runtime is not a problem, but install and configure mysql + php is).

Comment: *"I'd like to provide offline version of web with.."*, what are you referring to as *web* here, the world wide web?

Comment: No :-), I meant web site, a few html + JS files.

Comment: I just came across this, might be useful: [Semantic networks in languages other than English](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/related-projects/#semantic)